# Can't use the internet over wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, lubuntu, internet, network-manager

My Macbook 3,1 can connect to my router, but cannot use the connection. I have tried to solve this problem, but not smart enough to do so. That's why I'm turning to you.

How I am able to connect to the internet:

- On Windows XP through both wifi and ethernet with home router
- On Mac OSX 10.5 through both wifi and ethernet with home router
- On Lubuntu 14.04 through ethernet with home router
- On Lubuntu 14.04 through wifi with school router
- On Lubuntu 14.04 through unsecured wifi hanging in the neighbourhood

How I am **not** able to connect to the internet:

- On Lubuntu 14.04 through wifi with home router

I am able to connect to the router as shown in the picture below, but somehow I can't use the connection. **I can't even ping to the router** itself, while the laptop is showing up in the DHCP list of connections with the correct MAC address and the same Assigned IP address as you can see in the picture.

I am completely lost at to what the problem might be. Anybody knows where the problem might lay?!

[image: enter image description here!]

---

After running the script found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/258487) as suggested by [Wild Man](https://askubuntu.com/users/153297/wild-man), I got the following output. See [pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7936013/).

Comment: Can u connect to your own router if you keep it unlocked?

Comment: @orestis I disabled both mac filtering and the security and still the same problem... I can connect, but can't ping nor use the internet... I tried my phone and he can connect as usual.

Comment: This is a very long shot,but it may have to do with the wifi channels. I had a similar problem with one laptop and I found out that the laptop would work better in the channels in the middle. For a strange reason, both I had to declare the same country in both the router and the laptop in order for the laptop to work when the wifi channel was on the far-end i.e. channels 1,14.  You could also try setting your laptop a static address (and set the DNS server to 192.168.0.1). What happens when you use a live CD?

Comment: @orestis I tried channels 1,2,4,6,7,8 and 10, but no luck. I tried with the live CD, but even after installing the driver, my wireless card isn't showing up in ifconfig, nm-applet, etc... So I can't turn it on to even try.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: @WildMan pastebin output added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and let us have your report.

Comment: +1 Accepted from my laptop through wifi~~ Thanks!