# Can connect to only some networks after update 14.10

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, 14.10

I'm using Lubuntu 14.10 on my Macbook 3,1. I'm using the only available Airport driver `bcmwl-kernel-source` and it is working fine. I can connect to most networks, but not to all. Strangely enough I can wirelessly connect to my personally managed routers I installed at home, but not to those that are installed by others, like the router installed by my ISP at home or the routers at my uni.

So I would love to connect to all networks, but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem. I can connect to all those networks fine with my android smartphone, so for now I'm just USB tethering the connection, but it would be much better if I could connect directly.

I had troubles with wifi before as asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/505966/258487) and at that time the answer worked fine. I could connect to any wifi network, but after updating to 14.10, I tried this again and the only thing it did was remove my wifi functionality.

Does anybody know what the problem might be in 14.10 and how I can connect to all wifi networks?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/55868/258487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot

Comment: This solution worked only half for me. I am now able to connect to all devices, but only through the 2.4Ghz band. I can't seem to detect 5Ghz bands anymore.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: I ran the script for both [bcmwl](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10802460/) and [b43](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10802437/)

Comment: So in the first case I can not connect to *verdiep0*, *TELENETHOMESPOT* and *TelenetWiFree*, who are all managed by my ISP. Our ISP basically sends out a signal from every home that works as a hotspot for other clients to access the internet through other client's router, without interfering with their traffic. That's why you can see so many of them. Those three SSIDs all come from the same router, but respectively stand for my personal home network, unprotected access to the network (login required) and protected access to the network. In the second case I can't catch the 5Ghz channels.

Comment: I have been researching and it looks like the b43 driver does not support 5GHZ, but that is the exact same driver I helped you install in the link that you have in your question, the only change in 14.10 is the commands changed to install the driver. I suggest since the driver solved your issue of not being able to connect to certain networks as your question stated was the issue that you mark this answer accepted and start a new one about 5ghz issue. The b43 driver is the one used for 14.10 and it looks like the wl driver has a bug.

Comment: Thanks. Created [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/608523/258487) as requested.