# Cannot connect to 5GHz band with b43 driver

Tags: lubuntu, 14.10, broadcom, b43

I am using Lubuntu 14.10 on my Macbook 3,1 and I switched to the b43 driver as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/607750/258487). The problem I have with this driver is that I cannot detect and connect to the 5GHz band wifi networks.

Is there anything I could do to be able to connect to that frequency band again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kernel 3.17 and above there has been some success in getting 5GHZ to work with the b43 driver, so here are the directions for installing the 3.18 kernel, I can not promise that it might not cause some other kind of issues.

```
cd /tmp/

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18-vivid/linux-headers-3.18.0-031800-generic_3.18.0-031800.201412071935_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18-vivid/linux-headers-3.18.0-031800_3.18.0-031800.201412071935_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18-vivid/linux-image-3.18.0-031800-generic_3.18.0-031800.201412071935_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.18.0-*.deb linux-image-3.18.0-*.deb
```

Reboot

Set the channel manually on the router and in network manager that you want to connect to, make sure it is within the range of your devices channels by looking at the occupancy section in the file you posted. Changing the channel from auto to fixed is your best option.

Also linux connects best to wpa2 AES CCMP Only not mixed mode or TKIP.

Do:

```
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Reboot

Comment: I added directions that might help get 5GHZ working.

Comment: I can now detect the band, but cannot connect. It keeps asking for my password and despite giving the correct password it keeps configuring and re-asking the password.

Comment: Post the wireless script file like you did in your other question and hopefully we will see something that we can change.

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10823615/) you go. Thanks for the help man!

Comment: Added more directions

Comment: By deleting that file, I was able to connect back to my personal 5ghz network, but not to that of my ISP, see [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10857668/). That network gives the `association denied (code=18)` error. Seeing I can connect to its 2.7ghz network, I guess it doesn't matter much to me, so I'll just wait and see what the update to `15.04` brings. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the driver can't handle 11n connections.

Comment: I'm running on lubuntu 17.04 which has much newer kernel 4.4 and the issue still persists. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @mateuszlewko Please ask your own question and run the wireless script as the directions above shows and post the file to pastebin and the link in your question.   Thanks